# PostgreSQL Attendance and night shift

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series, time-and-attendance

i have following table:

| dt | type |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-12 21:36:26 | WORK_START |
| 2022-09-13 02:00:00 | BREAK_START |
| 2022-09-20 06:00:00 | WORK_START |
| 2022-09-20 10:00:00 | BREAK_START |
| 2022-09-20 10:27:00 | BREAK_END |
| 2022-09-20 13:00:00 | WORK_END |
| 2022-09-13 06:00:00 | WORK_END |
| 2022-09-13 02:30:00 | BREAK_END |

and query :

```
SELECT g.tempDatum::date as datum,
   MAX(att.dt::time) FILTER (WHERE att.type = 'WORK_START') as work_start
,  MAX(att.dt::time) FILTER (WHERE att.type = 'BREAK_START') as break_start
,  MAX(att.dt::time) FILTER (WHERE att.type = 'BREAK_END') as break_end
,  MAX(att.dt::time) FILTER (WHERE att.type = 'WORK_END') as work_end
FROM generate_series( '2022-09-01','2022-09-30', '1 day'::interval) AS g(tempDatum)
LEFT JOIN att ON att.dt::date = g.tempDatum::date group by g.tempDatum order by 
g.tempDatum;
```

Result is pretty good:

[Result photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV1l7.png)

except for **2022-09-12** because is a night shift. I want move Break_start + end and work_end to day 2022-09-12 for better result as attendance log.

How achieve this ? Big thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By grouping each work day (start, break start, break end, end) as one we can use `crosstab` to pivot it using the first work day of each group as the one for the entire day as requested.

```
select *
from   crosstab(
       'select min(dte) over(partition by grp), type, tme from 
        (
        select dt::date as dte
              ,dt::time as tme
              ,type
              ,row_number() over(order by dt,type)-case when row_number() over(order by dt,type) <= 4 then row_number() over(order by dt,type) else row_number() over(order by dt,type)-4 end as grp
        from   t
        ) t'   )
as     ct(dt date, WORK_START time, BREAK_START time, BREAK_END time, WORK_END time)
```

| dt | work_start | break_start | break_end | work_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-12 | 21:36:26 | 02:00:00 | 02:30:00 | 06:00:00 |
| 2022-09-20 | 06:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 10:27:00 | 13:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M7hZ0pLt?hide=4)